# Gnu Parallel recource limit per task?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu

is there any way to set resource limits for each job that gnu parallel is executing?

I am interested in a memory limit or a time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at --timeout (especially --timeout 1000% seems useful). For memory limit try:

```
ulimit -m 1000000
ulimit -v 1000000
```

to limit to 1 GB.

See also niceload and 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173762/gnu-parallel-limit-memory-usage/173860?noredirect=1#comment287065_173860